# MySQL empty sintax error 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I was executing in many ways (via php, via phpMyAdmin and via mysql client in terminal shell) a query, this query:
`SELECT id,titolo,luogo,data_ora FROM eventi WHERE data_ora BETWEEN(1293836400 AND 1296428400);`
And the result i get is always the same:
`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`
I tried executing it in the terminal splitted for get a better identification of the error and it seems to be in
`BETWEEN(1293836400 AND 1296428400);`
Is there anyone who can tell me what's wrong with my query!??

Comment: There's no brackets after BETWEEN.

Try 

    (BETWEEN 1293836400 AND 1296428400);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try eliminating the brackets from the BETWEEN clause:

```
SELECT .... data_ora BETWEEN 1293836400 AND 1296428400
```

Comment: Thanks, just a stupid syntax error, the brackets... Why have i put them?!